# Exportar DESCRIBE TABLE do Postgres para txt

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

É possível gerar um arquivo .txt com o DESCRIBE TABLE de uma tabela no Postgres pelo PHP?
Eu preciso disponibilizar o download de um arquivo .txt com a descrição dos campos(nome, tipo, tamanho de caracteres) da tabela onde está sendo feita a consulta.

Answer (score 0):

primeiro você pode fazer o select no INFORMATION_SCHEMA, e depois utilizar o Copy. Não sei se a formatação do texto te atende, mas é um ponto de partida.

Exemplo:

```
COPY (select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'nome_da_tabela') TO 'd:\nome_da_tabela.txt'
```